# Why am I getting an infinite loop from this while inside a for?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm enumerating `rawdata` and adding values to dedque `dex`

```
   for index, track in enumerate(rawdata):
        while index < 49:
            dex.append(track[0])
```

Comment: index is not incrementing within while loop.. it cannot exit it to change in outside for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of index is not changing inside the while loop. i.e, index is not been incremented.

`while index > 49  :` 
is always true.
Hence try incrementing the index value inside the while loop to exit out of the while loop and proceed to the next iteration of the outer for loop.

Comment: Thanks. That was really annoying me! -_-

Comment: Welcome @Stack Johan !